# Ampersand inside casting

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variables, reference, casting

I come across this code

```
int n1 = 10;
int n2 = (int &)n1;
```

I don't understand the meaning of this casting, n2 is not reference since modifying n1 doesn't reflect n1. Strangely this code throws compiler error in gcc where as compiles fine in VC++.

Anybody know the meaning of this casting?

Comment: My C++ is rusty but I think that a * could be used to either allocate an int or have a series of ints. I'm at a loss as to what the & would mean in this case though.

Comment: "modifying n1 doesn't reflect n1"??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `n2` is of some built-in type, the cast to `int &` type performs the *reinterpretation* of lvalue `n1` (whatever type it had) as an lvalue of type `int`.

In the context of `int n2 = (int &) n1` declaration, if `n1` is by itself an lvalue of type `int`, the cast is superfluous, it changes absolutely nothing. If `n1` is an lvalue of type `const int`, then the cast simply casts away the constness, which is also superfluous in the above context. If `n1` is an lvalue of some other type, the cast simply *reinterprets* memory occupied by `n1` as an object of type `int` (this is called *type punning*). If `n1` is not an lvalue the code is ill-formed.

So, in the code like `int n2 = (int&) n1` the cast to `int &` is only non-redundant (has some actual effect) when it does type punning, i.e when `n1` is an lvalue of some other type (not `int`). For example

```
float n1 = 5.0;
int n2 = (int &) n1;
```

which would be equivalent to

```
int n2 = *(int *) &n1;
```

and to

```
int n2 = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(&n1);
```

Needless to say, this is a pretty bad programming practice.

This is, BTW, one of the cases when using a dedicated C++-style cast is strongly preferred. If the author of the code used `reinterpret_cast` instead of C-style cast, you probably wouldn't have to ask this question.

Of course, if `n1` itself is of type `int`, there's no meaningful explanation for this cast. In that case it is, again, completely superfluous.

P.S. There's also a possibility that `n2` is a class with overloaded conversion operator to `int &` type, which is a different story entirely... Anyway, you have to tell what `n2` is when you ask questions like that.

Answer (score 11):

This is perfectly valid C++ code, and does compile with g++ 4.4.1.  It creates a temporary reference to n1 and then uses the value referred to by that reference to initialise n2.

This may be easier to see if expresed as a function:

```
void f( int & n1 ) {
   int n2 = n1;   // initialise with valuue referred to by n1
}
```

Note this is not valid C code, as C does not support references.

Comment: I'd say that in this context it is only "prefectly" valid in situations when it is superfluous, i.e. when `n1` itself has type `int`. When it is non-superfluous, it is a `reinterpret_cast`. Usually when you need to reinterpret memory occupied by an another object, the resultant code might be syntactically valid, but far from perfect, so to say.

Comment: I must admit, I assumed n1 was an int. Unless the OP respomds though, we may never know....

Comment: What's a "temporary reference"?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
        int n1 = 10;
        int n2 = (int &)n1;
        cout<<n2<<endl;
}
```

Prints 10 as expected.
There is no problem with the cast. 
It just creates a temporary reference as suggested by the next output:

```
int main()
{
        int n1 = 10;
        int n2 = (int &)n1;
        n2 = 20;
        cout<<n1<<endl; // print 10 and not 20.
}
```

Comment: So how is this different than just "int n2 = n1"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's probably a typo in the original code.

GCC is usually more pedantic than VC++. However this code seems fine even though it's doing unnecessary things. Basically a temp reference is created for n1 and then the copy constructor is used to instantiate n2.

Comment: operator=, surely? And if so, you would be wrong. The code shows an initialisation, not an assignment - they are different things in C++.

Comment: `n2` has type `int`. Type `int` is not a class type. It has no copy constructor. It has no constructors at all.

Comment: Another valid point. I guess the explanation above to all classes that aren't pod types in C++. For int, double, float would just do a normal assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It does the obvious thing. Cast `n1` to an int reference, and then assign it to the `int n2`.

And assuming `n1` is an int, it should compile just fine.

It won't compile if `n1` is a rvalue. The following won't compile, for example:

```
(int&)foo();
(int&)42;
(int&) (x+y); // assuming x and y are int variables
```

Comment: The last one will compile perfectly fine. Cast have higher precedence than addition. `(int&) x+y` means `((int&) x) + y`.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles in gcc too (I tried just to be sure). It simply casts n1 to a reference.